# Non exhaustive patterns in Haskell recursion

Tags: haskell, recursion, non-exhaustive-patterns

I'm trying to write a function which gives me the distance between every district in my list. The function `distance` gives me the distance between two districts as an `Int` from a set array, and I want to run through the whole list to sum up the distance between every district and its follower in the list.

But I'm getting the

> Non-exhaustive patterns

error message. What have I overlooked? The function `distance` is working as it should.

```
lengthr :: [district] -> Int
lengthr [] = 0
lengthr (a:b:as) = (distance a b) + lengthr (b:as)
```

Comment: What should happen if you give `lengthr` a list with exactly one element in it?

Comment: There would be no next destination to go to, so the distance should output 0.

Comment: Do you see any lines in your current function definition that would make that happen? If not, can you think of a line you could add that would?

Comment: In the future, compile with warnings on using `-Wall`: you will catch the error at compile time, and the error message will mention the case(s) you are missing.

Answer (score 3):

I added the line `lengthr [a] = 0` to my code, to cover up the case of only one element left, and now the code works as intended!

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned in your own answer, you were missing the case of a single element.

A more general solution is to include a catch-all pattern `_` after all of the specific cases you want to handle.

```
lengthr:: [district] -> Int
lengthr (a:b:as) = (distance a b) + lengthr (b:as)
lengthr _ = 0
```

This a more conventional way to handle default situations.

In situations where the result is contained in a `Monad` that has error semantics (e.g., `Either e` and `Maybe`), you can make the default case an error instead of potentially ignoring a bug.

```
lengthr:: [district] -> Either String Int
lengthr (a:b:as) = do
  next <- lengthr (b:as)
  Right $ (distance a b) + next
lengthr [_] = Right 0
lengthr _ = Left "empty list"
```